# Bad formatting in PhpStorm but much better formatting in Visual Studio Code. How to setup PhpStorm for better/same formatting?

Tags: visual-studio-code, format, phpstorm, code-formatting

I think I wrote everything in the headline. Here are two examples:

#### PhpStorm

[image: PhpStorm Part1]

[image: PhpStorm Part2]

#### Visual Studio Code

[image: Same Code after Insert and autoformat with basic Settings]

It seems that Visual Studio does his job much better but I'm completely into PhpStorm so I cant switch because of that right now. Do you have any ideas on how can I match the Code Format?

Here is the code-snippet

```html
<div <?php echo $this->cssID; ?> class="content--element <?php echo $this->class; ?>">
    <div class="ce--inner container">
        <?php if ($this->headline || $this->subline) : ?>
        <div class="ce--headline"
             data-aos="<?php if ($this->animation_type) : ?><?php echo $this->animation_type; ?><?php else : ?>animate__fadeInUp<?php endif; ?>">
            <?php if ($this->headline) : ?>
            <<?php echo($this->hl); ?>>
            <?php echo($this->headline); ?>
        </<?php echo($this->hl); ?>>
    <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($this->subline) : ?>
            <span class="ce--subline"><?php echo $this->subline; ?></span>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($this->boxes) : ?>
    <div class="row">
        <?php foreach ($this->boxes as $box) : ?>
        <div class="<?php if ($box->column_width) : ?><?php echo $box->column_width; ?><?php else : ?>col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4<?php endif; ?>">
            <div class="advantages--box"
                 data-aos="<?php if ($box->animation_type) : ?><?php echo $box->animation_type; ?><?php else : ?>animate__fadeInUp<?php endif; ?>">
                <?php if ($box->ce_headline) : ?>
                <div class="advantages--headline">
                    <?php if (!$box->onlystyle) : ?>
                    <<?php echo $box->headline_type; ?>>
                    <?php echo $box->ce_headline; ?>
                </<?php echo $box->headline_type; ?>>
            <?php if ($box->ce_subline) : ?>
                <span class="ce--subline advantages--subline">
                                                <?php echo $box->ce_subline; ?>
                                            </span>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php else : ?>
                <span class="<?php echo $box->headline_type; ?>">
                                            <?php echo $box->ce_headline; ?>
                                        </span>
                <?php if ($box->ce_subline) : ?>
                    <span class="ce--subline advantages--subline">
                                                <?php echo $box->ce_subline; ?>
                                            </span>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ($box->text) : ?>
                <div class="advantages--text">
                    <?php echo $box->text; ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please attach the snippet as code, it's much easier to work with text.

Comment: @EugeneMorozov I added the code :-)

Comment: Thanks! It helped to identify the problem, but it seems that there's nothing you can do to work the issue around - PhpStorm doesn't indent blocks that are interrupted by HTML tags: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-32908

Comment: @EugeneMorozov well thats bad news. thanks for clarification!